# How to specify list of subnets for ELB from the Parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb, subnet

I am trying to specify subnets for ELB based on the region type
This is what i have in my parameters for example

```
PublicSubnetsEastRegion:
  Description: List of public subnets in us-west-2 region 
  Default: 'subnet-0bc21846adc3391fa,subnet-044a6f3e47331f209,subnet-0277131ad616e1b50'
  Type: 'List<String>'
```

This is how i am referencing in ELB

```
BastionELB:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancing::LoadBalancer
    Properties: 

      ConnectionDrainingPolicy: 
        Enabled: !Ref ELBConfigConnectionDraining
        Timeout: !Ref ELBConfigConnectionDrainingTimeout

      SecurityGroups: 
        - !Ref BastionClientsdevELBIntuitSecurityGroup

      Subnets:
        - !If [ isRegionUS-WEST-2, !Ref PublicSubnetsWestRegion, !Ref PublicSubnetsEastRegion ]
```

But this keeps throwing the error subnets have to be of list type. How can i refer them in ELB based on the condition(that determines the region)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `-`. It should be:

```
   Subnets:
      !If [ isRegionUS-WEST-2, !Ref PublicSubnetsWestRegion, !Ref PublicSubnetsEastRegion ]
```